# xmllint doesn't return default value of attribute

Tags: xml, linux, bash, xmllint

I am using xmllint for reading a XML file.

Here is the XML Schema definition (schema.xsd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="machine">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>  
        <xs:element name="interface" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="default_ip" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>                   
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="enable_ipv6" default="yes">
              <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                  <xs:enumeration value="yes"/>
                  <xs:enumeration value="no"/>
                </xs:restriction>
              </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:attribute>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>    
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And here is the XML file I am trying to read (file.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<machine xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema.xsd">

  <interface name="eth1" enable_ipv6="yes">
    <default_ip>10.10.10.1/24</default_ip>
  </interface>

  <interface name="wlan0">
    <default_ip>20.20.20.1/24</default_ip>
  </interface>

</machine>
```

The XML file validates properly against the XSD file:

```
user@debian:~/Desktop/xml-example$ xmllint --noout --schema schema.xsd file.xml 
file.xml validates
```

The problem I have is that when I am trying to read an attribute that has not been set in the XML file, but has been set up with a default value in the XSD file, xmllint is not reading it.

For example, xmllint can read the value of the attribute "enable_ipv6" of the first interface (eth1):

```
user@debian:~/Desktop/xml-example$ xmllint --xpath 'string(/machine/interface[1]/@enable_ipv6)' file.xml 
yes
```

But returns nothing when trying to read the same attribute of the second interface (wlan0):

```
user@debian:~/Desktop/xml-example$ xmllint --xpath 'string(/machine/interface[2]/@enable_ipv6)' file.xml 
user@debian:~/Desktop/xml-example$
```

According to the XSD file definition, as the attribute has not been set in the XML file, xmllint should return the default value, that is "yes", but it is not doing it.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think it's because xmllint/libxml2 isn't schema aware. You'd have to use something like [Saxon-EE](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.8EE) that is schema aware (see [Schema-Aware XQuery from the Command Line](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!schema-processing/saquerycmd)).